# How to use realloc (strange behavior)

Tags: c, realloc

So I have a program and its work fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STACKDEFSIZE 1
typedef struct
{
  unsigned long int maxsize;
  unsigned long int cursize;
  unsigned long int* arr;
} stack;

stack* create_stack()
{
  stack* res = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
  res->arr = malloc(sizeof(long) * STACKDEFSIZE);
  res->maxsize = STACKDEFSIZE;
  res->cursize = 0;
  return res;
}

void push(stack* st, int val)
{
  if (st->cursize  == st->maxsize)
  {
    unsigned long int* old = st->arr;
    st->maxsize *= 2;
    st->arr = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long int) * st->maxsize);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < st->cursize; i++)
      st->arr[i] = old[i];
    free(old);
  }
  st->arr[st->cursize] = val;
  st->cursize += 1;
}

int main() {
  stack* s = create_stack();
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    push(s, i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But if I change function 'push' to use realloc instead of malloc and free, program crash with message " Error in `./t': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001031030
Aborted"

```
void push(stack* st, int val)    
{    
  if (st->cursize  == st->maxsize)    
  {    
    st->maxsize *= 2;    
    st->arr = realloc(st->arr, st->maxsize);    
  }    
  st->arr[st->cursize] = val;    
  st->cursize += 1;    
}
```

Also valgrind print message 'Invalid write of size 8' when I trying to use realloc.
What I doing wrong?
I use gcc and Debian Jessie x86_64.

Comment: in C, the returned type from any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the casting.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Could save some debugging by initializing the contents of struct stack to `0, 0, NULL`.  (realloc will handle a NULL pointer properly)

Comment: @user3629249 thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong size to `realloc`. As a consequence, your program runs into undefined behavior in no time.

Use:

```
st->arr = realloc(st->arr, sizeof(*st->arr)*st->maxsize);
```

Comment: Oh, really. Thank you very much!